# when should i use object.wait() method and when should i use Thread.sleep() in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

when should i use `object.wait()` method and when should i use `Thread.sleep()` in java?

In my understanding:

`Wait()` is used for `inter-thread` communication while `sleep()` is used to introduce a pause on execution of current thread, generally.

i am asking in the context of usecases of both the methods.for e:g problems like producer consumer can be solved by wait(), notify().

Comment: That's more or less right, but they're more different than the same. I would say that the times to use Object.wait() are very rare. Most of the time, you can (and should) use a higher-level class, like CountDownLatch or BlockingQueue.

Comment: And the times to use `Thread.sleep()` are even rarer.

Comment: Please see my edited question - it's not duplicate